# Views, path problem

Tags: views, 6, uri

My view path is: bartender/profiles/friends/%

In View UI if I provide argument everything works ok.

But in real when I go to ex. site.com/bartender/profiles/friends/20 I get a page from site.com/bartender url.

Could somebody help me solve this issue?

Comment: Permissions on the View maybe ... ? In the View UI, check Page Settings > Access ... ? Or Block Settings, if that is what you are using.

Comment: What defines the "/bartender" path? Is it another view?

Comment: Some additional details about the view and the expected content would help. Do you have any relationships defined? Any access control modules installed? Is the issue still present when logged in as superadmin(uid 1)? What are the settings for the argument? What happens when you set the argument to return a summary if nothing is provided?

Comment: bartender is static page. In page display I have no relantionships. There is no argument for page display.  I try to add menu item for this page but still with no luck. Issue for super admin is the same.

Comment: I try something like cocktails/ricerca?page=2 to force display views page but no success again. cocktails/ricerca is my another views page, but I see again cocktails pahe instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sub-path URL Aliasing module causing problem. After turn off all works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Drupal menu system strictly follow the menu paths.

According to my experience you do not need to add `%` sign while defining path.

Define your argument by adding an entry from Views UI (Argument Section)

`Provide default argument` to deal the scenario without page argument

Access is by default `unrestricted`. Check is as well

---

Drupal menu system travels from bottom to top.

e.g. path a/b/c/d is not valid then the content is showed from a/b/c similarly the process goes upward.

Your example is evident that your views is no receiving arguments and `bartender/profiles/friends` and `bartender/profiles` are invalid paths.

Comment: I check access and remove % from path. I still have the same issue :/

Comment: Now I create another views page. Path is bartender/leaders and again I see /bartender page content only

Comment: Might there be prefix slash in your views URL via the UI?

Comment: I create another views page cocktails/ricerca, and again it show cocktails static page :/