# How to stop hook_menu item being called

Tags: 7, routes

I have a function like:

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['cars'] = array(
    'title' => 'Cars',
    'page callback' => 'section_index',
    'page arguments' => array("cars"),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'file' => 'pages/section.inc',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
}
```

It works fine. Going to cars calls this page. I have a load of node pages like cars/ford and cars/volvo and they get called. However. If you go to cars/volvvvo (for example), it calls the "cars". No 404 is triggered etc.

This also seems to mean that the breadcrumb is glitchy for other pages called by hook_menu which have cars in the path, e.g.

```
 $items['cars/help'] = array(
    'title' => 'Cars Help',
    'page callback' => 'cars_help',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'file' => 'pages/help.inc',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

Has a mangled breadcrumb with additional paths to "cars" in it.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to stop additional arguments being just silently pased through via hook_menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't, see the following question/answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/33493/31

If you only want to allow certain arguments, you need to validate the argument and return MENU_NOT_FOUND. Or you can use a named argument, e.g. cars/%brand, which will automatically call the brand_load() function, pass the value of the parameter to it and if that function returns FALSE, then it's automatically returned as 404. This is used for node/%node, user/%user and so on.